# Checking if two or more records in sql already exist before Inserting in C#

Tags: c#

what I got so far is only available to check one record at a time, how can I check availability of multiple record in one click.

my code:

```
SqlDataAdapter sdb = new SqlDataAdapter("Select count(*) From reserve", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

sdb.Fill(dt);

if (int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) == 0)
{

  lblavailability2.Text = cbotime1.Text + cboemployee.Text + txtdate.Text
     + "TIME is Available"; 
}
else
{
   lblavailability2.Text = cbotime1.Text + cboemployee.Text + txtdate.Text
     + "TIME is NOT Available";
}
```

Comment: You are just checking if table has any records. What do you mean by *checking availability*? What do you have in `reserve` table? How do you define whether time is available?

Comment: yes. if table has the record already. what I mean is, how can I check cbotime, cboemployee and txtdate if their values is already taken (at the same time) and not as individuals. @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: As Sergey says... your SQL statement is only counting rows. ""Select count(*) From reserve". This will return you 1 number! How can you check whether a record exists unless the sql is based upon some other criteria..e.g. Where customer number = 1 and date = mar 13 2017

Comment: To execute SQL queries, use SqlCommand, not SqlDataAdapter. That class is only used to work with DataTables, which you don't need. To retrieve a single value, use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`. Apart from that, to check for someone's reservations you have to add a `WHERE` clause with the appropriate filter. Forget about C# - you have to create an appropriate SQL statement first.

Answer (score -1):

You Are Just Counting The Rows in reserve Table , Even If U Wanna Do That There Is No Need For A Whole Data Adapter Data Table To Store One Value In It , Consider Using `ExecuteScalar ()` in Such a Case Cause Ur Query Will Reutrn One Value .

First You Need Some Sort Of Identifier To Determine IF The Product Already Exists , Like ProductId , Then Before Inserting a a new Row You Can Check If The Id Is Already Existed In This Table and Return Message To The Use Saying That .

Also At Sql Level u could Use Unique Constraint  Or A SQL Trigger For Insert That Will Allow Only Values That Match Ur Condition